# In matlab,how to plot cdf graph?

Tags: matlab, plot, cdf

In matlab, if I have this code :

```
 v=10;
    for t=1:v
     Rateall(1:v) = (1/2)*(log2(1+SINR1)+log2(1+SINR2));
 distanceall(1:v)=pdist([randomclusters{1};randomclusters{2}],'euclidean');
    end
```

Rateall has 10 values and distanceall has 10 values after the for loop. How to plot the cdf graph between both Rateall and distanceall?

Comment: Your code makes no sense because you are setting `Rateall(1:v)` in each iteration of the loop. Either use `Rateall(t)` within the loop, or if possible fill it outside the loop using `Rateall(1:v)`. Same for `distanceall`.

Comment: Have you considered using `cumsum`?

Comment: @rayryeng **Warning, do not use `cumsum` right away!**. You need to make sure that a sample with higher weight have a larger impact on the cdf. Try something like `plot(sortedValues,cumsum(sortedWeights)/sum(sortedWeights))`. If all weights are equal, then `cumsum(sortedWeights) == 1:length(sortedWeights)` (when normalized)

Comment: @patrik - Of course.  My apologies.  Thank you for the suggestion.